# How to refresh bindings on click

Tags: knockout.js

I am creating a form with two checkboxes.

If the user checks checkbox 1, then 2 should be disabled.
If checkbox 2 is checked, then 1 should be disabled.
if the user unchecks 1, then 2 should be enabled.
if the user unchecks 2, then 1 should be enabled.

(I know this could be done with a radio button, but the actual use case has many checkboxes which can be checked.  This example has just two for simplicity of example.)

In other words, based on the user action, the remaining checkboxes will be enabled/disabled.

I have a binding expression on checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="refreshBindings(event)" data-bind="enable: getIsEnabled(1)" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="refreshBindings(event)" data-bind="enable: getIsEnabled(2)" value=2>


var currentId=0;

functionRefreshBindings(event)
{
    currentId = event.currentTarget.value;
    //How do I get the bindings to reevaluate getIsEnabled() for each item?   
}

function getIsEnabled(id) {
    switch (+id) {

        case 1:
            if(currentId===2)
                return false;
            else return true;
        case 2:
             if(currentId===1)                 
                return false;
             else
                return true;
                }
    return true;
}
```

So how to I get the bindings to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stay far from using things like `onclick` events and `value` properties when using Knockout. With MVVM try to rely on data-binding as much as possible. Knockout should refresh the enabled status automatically if you properly bind it.

For example, supposing this view:

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: shouldBeEnabled(propA), checked: propA" /> Check 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: shouldBeEnabled(propB), checked: propB" /> Check 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: shouldBeEnabled(propC), checked: propC" /> Check 3
```

This ViewModel should do what you request:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;   

    self.propA = ko.observable(false);
    self.propB = ko.observable(false);
    self.propC = ko.observable(false);

    self.shouldBeEnabled = function(myVal){
        if (myVal() === true) { return true; }
        return !self.propA() && !self.propB() && !self.propC();
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23U26/1/) for a demo.

Comment: PS. I much appreciate the simplification of your examples, but it may have been a wee bit too much. I suspect you may run into problems with my answer to that simplified problem (as your real view models are likely to have complex properties, and the checkboxes will probably be inside a `foreach` binding?). If that's the question be sure to ask a follow-up SO question and ping me here in the comments if you shouldn't get any response to the new question.

Comment: thank you very much for this.  I tried this and it does indeed force a re-evaluation of shouldBeEnabled.  But I don't get how it does this.  When the user clicks the box, it updates propA, but how does it trigger shouldBeEnabled(propA) to fire?

Comment: Knockout will make this work roughly as follows. The `enable` bindings rely on `propA` (etc), and KO will have a internal registry of those dependencies (initialized upon `applyBindings`). Every time `propA` (etc) changes it will re-evaluate the `enable` bindings. This two-way binding mechanism is *core* to MVVM and KO in particular.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I did a follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502381/how-to-wire-up-enable-on-checkbox-with-viewmodel which includes a jsfiddle.