# How to wire up enable on checkbox with ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am just learning knockout.js.  After much work, I got this small viewmodel working, but the shouldBeEnabled method of the ViewModel seems pretty clunky.  Is there a better way to bind this?

What I am trying to achieve is that if the first item is selected, the user cannot select the third item, and vice versa (the user can't select the first item, if he has selected the 3rd.)

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregoryagu/rarKK/5/)

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind=" enable: shouldBeEnabled(reportType9, 9), checked:    reportType9    "  />Check 1
<br />

<input type="checkbox" data-bind=" enable: shouldBeEnabled(reportType11, 11), checked: reportType11" />Check 2

<br />
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind=" enable: shouldBeEnabled(reportType12, 12), checked: reportType12" />Check 3



function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.reportType9 = ko.observable(false);
    self.reportType11 = ko.observable(false);
    self.reportType12 = ko.observable(false);

    self.shouldBeEnabled = function (isChecked, id) {

            switch (id) {
                case 9:
                    if (isChecked()) {
                        self.reportType12();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (self.reportType12()) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                    break;

                case 12:

                    if (isChecked()) {
                        self.reportType9();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (self.reportType9()) {
                            return false;
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;
            }

    };

}



$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the logic right into the view:

```
enable: reportType12() === false
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/4kc3U/)**

Generic sample: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/JLQqx/)**

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  data-bind="enable: check2() === false, checked: check1"
>
<label>Check 1</label>

<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  data-bind=" enable: check1() === false, checked: check2"
>
<label>Check 2</label>
```

Comment: I'm assuming the reason this was downvoted is that the downvoter does not understand that frameworks such as Knockout encourage view logic being declared in the view.

Comment: I downvoted because the "`check2() === false`" bit is *logic* and should be in the ViewModel (for one because it is then easier to unit test, aggreeing with @AnthonyChu in his comments on his answer). One of KnockoutJS' authors also [touches on the issue](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/08/simplifying-and-cleaning-up-views-in.html). (PS. No need to be snarky and assume "...the downvoter *does not understand*..."; the downvoter may (or may not) be correct or at the least sincere in downvoting.)

Comment: @Jeroen I stand by my "snarkiness". I appreciate your view and that you presented that article and a reason for your downvote. In some sitations, it's more than reasonable to downvote something and move on, but you're not doing anyone a favor (me, the OP, or future viewers) in this case by not presenting a reason. I definitely got some perspective from the article and am glad to have read it. I still don't know what to believe, because Angular seems to argue the opposite (my stance). They even add features promoting the power of inline logic (ternary support added in 1.1.5).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the logic out of your view, you can also use `computed`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2MQP/

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.reportType9 = ko.observable(false);
    self.reportType11 = ko.observable(false);
    self.reportType12 = ko.observable(false);

    self.reportType9Enabled = ko.computed(function () {
        return !self.reportType12();
    });

    self.reportType11Enabled = ko.computed(function () {
        return true;
    });

    self.reportType12Enabled = ko.computed(function () {
        return !self.reportType9();
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

View...

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind=" enable: reportType9Enabled, checked: reportType9    "  />Check 1
<br />

 <input type="checkbox" data-bind=" enable: reportType11Enabled, checked: reportType11" />Check 2

<br />
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind=" enable: reportType12Enabled, checked: reportType12" />Check 3
```

Comment: I got downvoted at the same time you got upvoted here, so I just would like to question this - as far as I know, Angular, Knockout, etc encourage view logic being in the view. Your answer makes sense to me for some more complicated calculations, but for this, it's simply more code to write for no advantage. The intent is still in the view (the function name) while the result is elsewhere. It would be easiest for both to be in one place if possible.

Comment: @m59: Maybe the thinking is that the logic here (though simple) is business logic, not view logic; so it ideally should be in the view model. This is more apparent if we want to write tests to verify the behavior, as it's much easier to do so on the vm. Looking back, perhaps naming the `computed` with the word "Enabled" can be confused with view logic. Something like "Allowed" would be better. IMO, the type of logic that should be in the view should be so simple that it doesn't need testing (direct data bindings, loops, negations").

Comment: @AnthonyChu Well said. I don't see what the issue with testing would be. I think it's most ideal that if possible, ALL of the view logic would be in the view (not likely to happen, obviously). That wouldn't stop me from writing a test to check a checkbox and test if another one is thusly disabled. What it would do is save bytes and increase readability. Regardless of where the logic is, it's bound to the javascript view model, so why would it affect testing?

Comment: @m59 Writing a test to test a JavaScript object is much easier to do than testing the DOM. Another reason you want as much business logic (and no view-specific logic) in the view model as possible is reuse. This makes it much easier to use the vm in another app with a totally different UI (maybe a PhoneGap or WinJS app).

Comment: I guess I can see it either way :) I'm not at all convinced it's downvote worthy or that my preference is bad practice.

Comment: @m59 For what it's worth, I saw your answer after posting mine and upvoted it because it was such a simple solution.  :)